# modifying attribute in $self using regex

Tags: regex, perl, object, whitespace, moose

I am new to perl and i am having issues in modifying an attribute under saved in `$self`.

I have an attribute called "devices" inside `$self`, if I print it in perl debugger it prints like this :

```
DB<22> x $self->{devices}
0  ARRAY(0xa1ec308)
0  "BG-SOKU-SAA01\cM\cJBG-SOKU-TS01 BG-SOKU-DCN01"
```

Now I want to replace `\cM\cJ` and whitespace with commas in the above attribute. So I am writing a regex for it which is like this :

```
my @dM= @{$self->{devices}};
$dM[0]=~ s/\cM\cJ/,/g;
$dM[0]=~ s/ /,/g;
```

Now when I print the `$self->{devices}` it gives me this :

```
DB<22> x $self->{devices}
0  ARRAY(0xa1ec308)
0  'BG-SOKU-SAA01,BG-SOKU-TS01,BG-SOKU-DCN01'
```

RegEx works but when I pass it to some other class and try to iterate over it, it takes comma separated device names as one single value rather than taking 1 device name each.

I dont know what is going wrong.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: I think we need a bit more sample code. Because that example you give - that shouldn't work, because you're _copying_ `$self -> {devices}` into a temporary variable. But it's likely that your comma separated names are a string, not an array, which is why it's being treated as a single value.

Comment: I think you are not showing the real output of the debugger in your second DB statement. It's the same _round_ of debugging (22) and the array's address is the same. Please show the real output. Also, did you make that change with `@dM` in your code and reran the debugger, or did you do that in the debugger's console? Maybe the debugger is a bit of an overkill tool right now, and you should consider starting with a simple `print Dumper $self`. Or better, use Data::Printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem will be that `$self -> {devices}` is actually a single element array - containing the string `'BG-SOKU-SAA01,BG-SOKU-TS01,BG-SOKU-DCN01'`

The implication is you want this to be an array - this is relatively easily achieved via `split`

```
@{$self -> {devices}} = map { split /,/ } @{$self -> {devices}}
```

Given you're *already* transforming on delimiters first though - you can probably do the same on that.

```
@{$self -> {devices}} = map { split /(?:\\cM\\cJ|\s+)/ } @{$self -> {devices}}
```

`map` is one of those "dark magic" perl functions - what it does is list transformation.

- We take the source list - in this case `@{$self -> {devices}}`
- iterate through it applying a code block. `split /,/` - this returns zero or more elements (we split each element on commas), which is added to the *new* list.
- and then we assign the new list.

This is basically the same as:

```
my @new_list;

foreach my $element ( @{$self -> {devices}} ) {
    my @tmp = split /,/, $element;
    push ( @new_list, @tmp ); 
}

$self -> {devices} = \@new_list;
```

The second example is essentially the same, but using the fact that `split` can take a regular expression.

By using: `(?:\\cM\\cJ|\s+)`

So we call either: `\cM\cJ` a delimiter *or* `\s+` which is regular expression for "one or more whitespace". Which is why it handles tabs, linefeeds, multiple spaces etc.

Note - the `(?:` at the start is important, because it denotes a non capturing group. If you use a capture (`()` usually) then that will be 'returned' as part of the map operation, so you'll end up with an unwanted element `\cM\cJ` because the regular expression captured it.

Try getting to grips with `Data::Dumper`.

```
use Data::Dumper;
```

then

```
print Dumper $self;
```

This will help you understand the contents of your object.

Comment: Or just split on whitespace and `\cM\cJ` to avoid the comma transformation.

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot for your help. As i am new to perl I did not know this way. Can you also explain me the what you exactly did here ? Coz 2nd line of code that you gave is handling all the scenarios newline,whitespace & tabs as well...!!

Comment: Explanation added. Hopefully that makes it a little clearer?